# How to get value of text box embeded in cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code

```
<tr val='question'>
    <td>
        <input style='width: 500px' type='text' placeholder='Q.Enter your question here for radio button? '>
</tr>
```

How can i find the value of input box embedded in cell .

```
function saveUserDefQues(){

var table=document.getElementById("QuestionList");
var surveyquestionform=document.forms[0];
var count=$('#QuestionList tr').length
for (var i = 0; i<count; i++) {
var row = table.rows[i];
if(row.getAttribute('val')==='question')
    {
    var Cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Under what event on which element are you trying to find this `input`? Also note that your HTML is invalid; `val` isn't a valid attribute for the `tr`, and you're missing a `</td>`

Comment: Can you add an `id` to the input element?

Comment: there is a button and onclick even i am retrieving all  value of this input box

Comment: @abhishek add your button click event scripts here

Comment: cant add id it is used to generate dynamic code

Comment: @abhishek you are mixing both javascript and Jquery syntaxes,.. Consider using either of them to keep the code clean..

Comment: Ok thst's a good suggestion but first i want the value of that input text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('tr[val] > td > input').value;
```

---

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr[val] > td > input')).forEach(function(entry, index, entries)
{
    entry.value; // you may store the value OR process with it AS you see fit
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Jquery this can be done this way.

replace this  line of code

`var Cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");`

with

`var Cells = $(row).find('td');`

`var inputValue = Cell.find('input').val();  // gives you value of input`

---

**Code Refactoring recommended**

I would like to refactor your code as below

**HTML**

```
<tr data-val='question'>     // use data-* attribute to add custom attributes into tags
    <td>
        <input style='width: 500px' type='text' placeholder='Q.Enter your question here for radio button? '>
    </td>                    // close your td
</tr>
```

**Script**

```
function saveUserDefQues(){      

 var surveyquestionform = document.forms[0];  // not sure what this is for, so ill leave it as is.

 $('#QuestionList tr[data-val="question"]').each(function(){ //loop all tr's  which has the data-val set to question     
   var inputValue = $(this).find('td input').val();          //get the value of input
   console.log(inputValue);            
 });  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("tr[val='question'] > td > input").val()`

But first you need to write a valid HTML. `</td>` closing tag is missing. Also you need to put this `tr` in a `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

[See this Plunker](http://codepen.io/ritesh14887/pen/LNJKJO)

```
function getResult(){
    $( "tr" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log($(this).find('input').attr('placeholder') );
});
}
```